# How to set female percentage in netlogo?

Tags: modeling, agent, netlogo

I have this code that set the age ranges kid,adult and old. How to set some of them that will be women by using slider?
I only want to set up females and males. like if you set the slider to 30%. 30% from the kid,adult and old breed will become female

```
breed [kids kid]

breed [adults adult]

breed [oldies old]



to set-up

  __clear-all-and-reset-ticks

  ask patches [setup-world]

  ask patches with [pcolor = brown ][set plabel count turtles-here]

  set-default-shape turtles "person"


   create-kids number-of-kids 
  [set speed random-float speed-kids
    set body random-float kids-size
    ]


  create-adults number-of-adults 
  [set speed random-float speed-adults
    set body random-float adults-size]

  create-oldies number-of-oldies
  [set speed random-float speed-oldies
    set body random-float oldies-size]

  ask kids[

    set color green
    if(body > 0.9)[
    set size body]         
    setxy random 19 random 80
    facexy 18 43]

  ask adults[

    set color orange
      if(body > 0.9)[
    set size body]                       
    setxy -10 0
    setxy random 19 random 80
    facexy 18 43]

  ask oldies[

    set color blue
      if(body > 0.9)[
    set size body]                                 
    setxy -10 0
    setxy random 19 random 80
    facexy 18 43]
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to keep track of people who are both female and fit into certain age ranges?

Comment: nope.I only want to set up females and males. like if you set the slider to 30%. 30% from the kid,adult and old breed will become female.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all turtles have a `is-female?` property and a slider named `percent-female`:

```
 turtles-own [is-female?]`
```

One way is to calculate 30% of each of the populations with something like:

```
ask n-of (percent-female / 100 * count kids) of kids [set is-female? true]
```

The other, somewhat more *Nelogo-ish* way, would be to to do it probabilistically when creating the kids, adults and oldies. eg:

```
    ask kids[
        if random 100 < percent-female [set is-female? true]
        set color green
        if(body > 0.9)[
        set size body]         
        setxy random 19 random 80
        facexy 18 43]
```